Multinomial glm(m) with predictors varying over item/response combinations
I have multinomial data where there are 4 items (categories) and many responses. For each response the size of the multinomial can exceed one (i.e. a response may be c(10,20,3,0)).
The predictors I would like to fit may vary over items only or vary over item/response combinations. MCMCglmm can fit such models in a straightforward way by using the term 'trait' which indexes levels of item. However, the data set is large (>4 million responses) so a non-MCMC approach would be preferable.
Does anyone know of an R package that can fit such models - preferably with random effects also.
